# My mousepressed() function isn't getting called?

Tags: java, eclipse

and thanks for clicking on this question. For my java class right now, I am trying to make a graph that draws a dot every time I click on it in the location of the mouse. Here's the code for my gui window:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUIWindow {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame theGUI = new JFrame();
        theGUI.setTitle("Drawing Program");
        theGUI.setSize(300, 200);
        theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(Color.white);
        Container pane = theGUI.getContentPane();
        pane.add(panel);
        theGUI.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

That just sets up my Gui and its dimensions. Here is my other class, where I try to do the mouseClick() function:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ColorPanel extends JPanel {

private int x, y;

public ColorPanel(Color backColor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    setBackground(backColor);
    addMouseListener(new PanelListener()); //the mouselistener is added here
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int x = getWidth() / 2; //this just makes it so the graph lines stay centered if the window is resized.
    int y = getHeight() / 2;


    g.setColor(Color.black);  //draws graph and sets (0,0)
    g.drawLine(x, 0, x, (y * 2));
    g.drawLine(0, y, (x * 2), y);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawOval(x-5, y-5, 10, 10);
    g.drawString("(0, 0)", x - 13, y - 10);


}

public void drawPoint(){

    Graphics g = getGraphics(); //this function uses the info taken from the mouseclick function and makes a small circle there.

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawOval(x, y, 5, 5);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 5, 5);
}

private class PanelListener extends MouseAdapter{
    //mouse press class. Gets x and y, and calls the drawpoint function.

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        System.out.println("lll"); //tester to see if the mosepress class is getting run. It doesn't.
        drawPoint();
    }

     /*public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e) {} 
     public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e) {} 
     public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e) {}  
     public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e) {} 
     */
    }
}
```

There are no errors in the code that I can see, the mouseclick just doesn't work. The printline you see doesn't print, which means for some reason the mouseclick function isn't being called. I've stared at this for days and have had a friend take a look, and we have no clue what's going on. If you could help me out, I would appreciate it a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Believe it or not, I copy-pasted these two classes, and it works for me. Draws circles and prints the "lll".

Comment: Your code is working fine. By any chance, are you confused with mouseClicked() vs mousePressed(). mouseClicked() happens when you press and release the mouse

Comment: Really? Weird...

Comment: check if you're compiling this correctly and if you're actually running the latest compiled code.  Also, attach a debugger (and by doing so, you'll notice very quickly if your're running outdated code).